# Android project, after migrating to gradle version 4.0+ ain't buildable

Tags: android, gradle

It is a third time I'm trying to migrate the big project to the new gradle versions but every time I'm stuck on the eternal loop (or out of memory erro) of build. I've already tried different versions of gradle and gradle plugin, but project highest buildable gradle version is still 3.3.2.

If the build fails the console tells, that daemons (or process, if the build is daemonless) are out of memory. The steps I've already tried so far:

1. List item
2. Different 4+ versions of gradle. Same result
3. Parallel == true and Parallel == false build. Same result
4. Daemon and daemonless builds. No result
5. Increasing the memory available for JVM (I've seen information, that since gradle 4.0 the amount of default memory available was set to 512 instead of 1024) up to 2048. No result
6. Scanning the build with -debug and other commands of gradlew. The only result I've seen is out of memory stack trace, which started since 'compileAnnotationProcessor'

Comment: Please upload build.gradle and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Can try these things if the build is failed -

1. Run Android SDK manager in menu option 'window'
2. You will see the Android Build-Tools version installed...

Change build.gradle to reflect the installed version of build tools

if any version error you are seeing, fix that.